# DHT22 Temp sensor - first time connected very high readings

Tags: sensor, wiringpi, dht22

I have just connected a DHT22 sensor to my RPi3. I have a 10k resistor between the data line and the 3.3v.

The readings i am getting when I run loldht are very high (Humidity 1100.8 % and Temp 614.4 *C)

Can anyone explain why please? Is this a dodgy sensor? Or am i missing something obvious?

Thanks in advance.

P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dodgy software.  Obviously no attempt has been made in the software to check the data for integrity.  Find some different software, there are plenty of Pi alternatives.

Here is one of my offerings (requires the pigpio daemon to be running).

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2_DHTXXD

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have tried a few different packages now and all are returning values of 1000+ for humidity and 500+ for Temp.

Comment: @pmcmurrough How odd.  Can you add a screen shot to your question?  Perhaps you are misreading the output.